# How to connect to a wifi using CMD?

Tags: cmd

I want to learn how to connect to someone's wifi that I haven't been connected to before using CMD

Answer (score 1):

command : netsh wlan add profile filename="C:\Users\m\Documents\wi-fi-wifiname.xml" Interface="WI-FI" user=current (enter)

command : netsh wlan connect ssid=YOUR_WIFI_NAME name=PROFILE_NAME (enter)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).